# IO and doing logic take a long time?

Tags: java, performance, servlets, hash, io

I am going to ask kind of a serious question. I have a file with "sentences" and the file size is 500MB. Since it take a long time to read, I created a *Hash* for this and saved it to another file (I first gathered list of words which will be in my program. Then created hashes for them. Then I added this into a `HashMap` so the 'key' is the word and the 'value' is the hash. My using this `HashMap` I converted the entire 500MB into a separate Hash file). Now this Hash is 77 MB. This hash can represent any word using 3 characters, and it create unique hashes for each word. One line in this Hash indicates one sentence in real file.

Now, I am going to enter a list of words into the program. Program will convert these words to *Hash* too. Then it will go through the Hash file I explained before (77MB) and find whether the words I entered are presented in the list (I am comparing Hashes). If presented, then I get the word (Hash indication of the word), convert it to the real word. Below is my program.

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.LinkedList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import javax.servlet.RequestDispatcher;

/**
 *
 * @author XXX
 */
public class Analizer extends HttpServlet {

    private static final String[] symbols = { "0", "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h",
        "i", "j", "k", "l", "m", "n", "o", "p", "q", "r", "s", "t", "u", "v", "w", "x", "y", "z", "!", "@", "#", "$", "%", "^", "&",
        "*", "~", "?" };
    private HashMap wordMap;
    PrintWriter pw;
    private HttpServletRequest request;
    private HttpServletResponse response;


    public void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException
    {
        doPost(request,response);
    }

    public void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)throws ServletException, IOException
    {

        this.request = request;
        this.response = response;

        String[] listOfWords = request.getParameter("wordList").toLowerCase().trim().split("\n"); //Get the List of words
        int percentage = Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("percentage")); // Get the percentage value
        double numberOfWordsInProgramHash = 0; //Keep track of how many words in "program" per webpage
        int primaryKey = 0; //Store the primary key
        StringBuffer hashIndex = new StringBuffer();
        LinkedList<DataHolder> storeDataHolders = new LinkedList<DataHolder>();

        StringBuilder userListWithoutDuplicates = new StringBuilder();

        pw = response.getWriter();

        double numberOfKnownWords = 0;


        Arrays.sort(listOfWords);

        //Remove the duplicated words in user's list
        HashSet<String> userDefinedSet = new HashSet<String>();

        for(int i=0;i<listOfWords.length;i++)
        {
            if (!userDefinedSet.contains(listOfWords[i].trim())) 
            {
                userListWithoutDuplicates.append(listOfWords[i].trim());
                userListWithoutDuplicates.append(" ");
            userDefinedSet.add(listOfWords[i].trim());

                //pw.println(listOfWords[i].trim());
        }
        }

        //createHashForUserList(userListWithoutDuplicates);
        hashIndex = createHashForUserList(userListWithoutDuplicates);


        //Read the Hash File
        String str = "";
        File inputFile = new File("C:/Users/Yohan/Desktop/Test.txt");

        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(inputFile));
        int pageNumber=0;

        while((str=br.readLine())!=null)
        {
            HashSet<String>hashSet = new HashSet<String>();
            ArrayList<String>matchingWordsHolder = new ArrayList<String>();
            ArrayList<String>unmatchingWordsHolder = new ArrayList<String>();

            int lastIndex = 0;


            for(int i=0;i<=str.length();i=i+3)
            {
                lastIndex = i;
                try
                {
                    String stringPiece = str.substring(i, i+3);
                  //  pw.println(stringPiece);
                    hashSet.add(stringPiece);
                }
                catch(Exception arr)
                {
                    String stringPiece = str.substring(lastIndex, str.length());
                  //  pw.println(stringPiece);
                    hashSet.add(stringPiece);
                }
            }

            numberOfWordsInProgramHash = hashSet.size();
            //pw.println("HASH sets size: "+numberOfWordsInProgramHash);

            //Create the Hash for the user input
            String[] finalUserDefinedWordCollection = hashIndex.toString().trim().split(" ");

            //Check how many words exists
            for(int i=0;i<finalUserDefinedWordCollection.length;i++)
            {

                if(hashSet.contains(finalUserDefinedWordCollection[i]))
                {
                    matchingWordsHolder.add(finalUserDefinedWordCollection[i]);
                    //pw.println(finalUserDefinedWordCollection[i]);
                    hashSet.remove(finalUserDefinedWordCollection[i]);
                    numberOfKnownWords++;
                }

            }

            //Making a list of words do not exists
            Iterator iter = hashSet.iterator();

            while(iter.hasNext())
            {
              unmatchingWordsHolder.add(iter.next().toString());
            }

            double matchingPercentage = ((numberOfKnownWords/numberOfWordsInProgramHash)*100.0);
            //pw.println("Page No: "+pageNumber+"  Number Of Matches: "+numberOfKnownWords+"   Matching Percentage: "+String.valueOf(matchingPercentage));
            //pw.println();

            if(matchingPercentage>percentage)
            {
                DataHolder data = new DataHolder(); //This is a custom class

                data.setOriginalHash(str);
                data.setPrimaryKey(pageNumber);

                StringBuffer matchingWordsStr = new StringBuffer("");
                    StringBuffer unMatchingWordsStr = new StringBuffer("");

                    //Populating Strings
                    for(int m=0;m<matchingWordsHolder.size();m++)
                    {

                        Iterator iterInWordMap = wordMap.entrySet().iterator();

                        while(iterInWordMap.hasNext())
                        {
                            Map.Entry mEntry = (Map.Entry)iterInWordMap.next();

                            if(mEntry.getValue().equals(matchingWordsHolder.get(m)))
                            {
                                //out.println(matchingWords.get(m)+" : "+true);
                                matchingWordsStr.append(mEntry.getKey());
                                matchingWordsStr.append(",");
                            }
                        }

                    }

                    data.setMatchingWords(matchingWordsStr);

                    for(int u=0;u<unmatchingWordsHolder.size();u++)
                    {
                        Iterator iterInWordMap = wordMap.entrySet().iterator();

                        while(iterInWordMap.hasNext())
                        {
                            Map.Entry mEntry = (Map.Entry)iterInWordMap.next();

                            if(mEntry.getValue().equals(unmatchingWordsHolder.get(u)))
                            {
                                //out.println(matchingWords.get(m)+" : "+true);
                                unMatchingWordsStr.append(mEntry.getKey());
                                unMatchingWordsStr.append(",");
                            }
                        }
                    }

                data.setUnmatchingWords(unMatchingWordsStr);

                storeDataHolders.add(data);
                //pw.write("Record Added to DataHolder");
            }

            numberOfKnownWords = 0;
            primaryKey++;
            pageNumber++;

        }


        //Grab the first 1000 items from LinkedList
        List<DataHolder> firstTenItems = new ArrayList<DataHolder>();


        for(int i=0;i<storeDataHolders.size();i++)
        {
            firstTenItems.add(storeDataHolders.get(i));

            if(i==9)
            {
                break;
            }
        }

        //Convert the Hashed words back to real words


        request.setAttribute("list", firstTenItems);

        RequestDispatcher dispatch = request.getRequestDispatcher("index.jsp");
        dispatch.forward(request, response);
    }

    /*
     * This method is responsible for creating the Hash List for the entire list of words
     * we have, and creating the Hash for the User desined word list
     * */
    private StringBuffer createHashForUserList(StringBuilder userListWithoutDuplicates)
    {
        System.out.println("Calling createHashForUserList()");

        createWordNumberingMap();

        String[]finalWordHolder = userListWithoutDuplicates.toString().split(" ");
        StringBuffer hashIndex = new StringBuffer();

        //Navigate through text and create the Hash
    for(int arrayCount=0;arrayCount<finalWordHolder.length;arrayCount++)
    {

         if(wordMap.containsKey(finalWordHolder[arrayCount]))
         {
            hashIndex.append((String)wordMap.get(finalWordHolder[arrayCount]));
                hashIndex.append(" ");
         }

    }




        return hashIndex;
    }



    //Hash Generating Algorithm
    public static String getSequence(final int i) {
    return symbols[i / (symbols.length * symbols.length)] + symbols[(i / symbols.length) % symbols.length]
            + symbols[i % symbols.length];
    }


    //Create Hashes for each word in Word List
    private Map createWordNumberingMap()
    {
        int number = 0;
        wordMap = new HashMap();
        BufferedReader br = null;
        String str = "";

        //First Read The File
        File readingFile = new File("D:/Eclipse WorkSpace EE/HashCreator/WordList/NewWordsList.txt");
        try
        {
            br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(readingFile));
            while((str=br.readLine())!=null)
            {
                  str = str.trim();
                  String id = getSequence(number);
                  wordMap.put(str,id);
                  number++;
                  System.out.println(id);

            }

            br.close();
            System.out.println("Completed");
            System.out.println(wordMap.get("000"));
            System.out.println("Last Number: "+number);
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        finally
        {
            try
            {
                    br.close();
            }
            catch(Exception e)
            {
                    e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        return wordMap;
    }


}
```

I tried my best to reduce the code so I can post something short. Above code is still big, but without all of its parts, you will not understand it.

Now my question is, my program is very very slow. If I insert 50 words into the application, it take more than 1 hour to do the work I explained before. I have tried 2 weeks to find a solution, but I could not. FYI, it takes no longer than 12 seconds to read the 77MB Hash file. Something else is wrong.

Comment: `for(int i=0;i<storeDataHolders.size();i++)`
does this loop goes to 1000 elements or 10 elements? Above comment implies 1000 but it breaks at 9. If you changed it for HN and actually 1000 that might be one of the reasons because you are accessing a linked list using get() method which traverse the list everytime you call it

Comment: @taytay: Sorry, 1000.

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered trying to measure the time taken by some of your loops to try to identify where the work heavy parts are?